# Drupal is not saving fields

Tags: drupal-7, field, custom-fields

I have 50 fields in a Content Type, when i hit save after dragging / reordering some fields, Drupal crashes and didnt save the data. No Error in Log as well.

I have tried changing the max_post_size and Memory_limit but nothing happens.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

max_input_vars - that's the answer.
This should be in your php.ini file.